# Error in Conversion from Generic List<Datarow> to Generic List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compiler-errors

I have the code below

```
List<string> esfa = NewTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("Select")   
=="true").ToList();
```

While compile getting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Datarow>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, yes. You're *filtering* by the `Select` field - but the result of that filtering is still a sequence of rows. I would expect that to be what you want - after all, you know the value of the `Select` field in every row, so that can't be interesting...

I think you probably just want:

```
List<DataRow> rows = NewTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Select") == "true")
                             .ToList();
```

(Note that breaking the code into multiple lines like this can greatly aid readability.)

If you actually wanted the value of some other field, you might want something like:

```
List<string> rows = NewTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Select") == "true")
                            .Select(row => row.Field<string>("LastName"))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon I guess that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
List<string> esfa = db.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Select") == "true")
                      .Select(s => s.Field<string>("Select"))
                      .ToList();
```

linq `.Select` enables you to select any of the properties of the current collection. Use any other useful field other than "Select" column.

Comment: That's unlikely to be useful, as it will be a list of "true", "true", "true", "true", ...

Comment: It was just to give him an idea about .Select :)